# how to include gensim into pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pycharm, gensim

As I was trying to use Gensim to do some plain-text extraction from PDFs. However I encountered problems with using this library.

I followed the instructions on the [website](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tutorial.html) and it seemed to work properly.

I also have downloaded a Python IDE called Pycharm. But then when I am trying to do the "quick example" from [here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tutorial.html). I got some errors in my Pycharm. The logging activation has no errors, but the line `from gensim import corpora, models, similarities` isn't working. The IDE hints me that the word `gensim` (and the other three words) is `unresolved reference`.

So I think that maybe I need to do something to try to link Gensim as a reference library. But I am a totally newbie to python so I hope that someone can tell me how to do it. Or someone has worked with Gensim may also help me with this problem. Any ideas?

By the way, I am using python3 for the project as well.

Comment: Which version of Anaconda do you have in your machine? Open up a terminal, and type python and enter. import gensim and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Do '**pip install gensim**' from cmd or terminal or git bash. If your anaconda environment is set, it will be installed for anaconda automatically ( at least this happens on windows.) If using that doesn't work try doing: **conda install gensim**.

You can check which interpreter your pycharm is using by going to **File** -> **settings** -> **Project:'your project name'** -> **project interpreter**.

There in the drop down u can choose the interpreter you want. **Best** is to switch to anaconda and then do pip install gensim. Why anaconda ? Because it will give you a lot of packages, that you don't need to install manually later on.

Answer (score 0):

1) Open the project interpreter from settings and click on the + to the right.
2) You get a list of packages. 
3) Search for gensim and click install package. 
4) This will add it to the interpreter in PyCharm